# Test Ads On Real Devices, Not Simulator (SpriteKit, Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob, ads

I have test ad code in my xcode project so when I run the simulator it shows a test banner, it shows a real banner when I run it on my device, even without deleting the test code. Does that mean the ads arent test ads? Because I submitted my app to the app store and I'm wondering if I left the test code in, so I'm worried the ads might not work.

Answer (score 0):

GADRequest has a property testDevices, in which you should list simulator, your phone, etc. Any device that is not listed as a test device should get regular ads.

I'm not sure how you implemented 'test ad code', but sounds like it includes only a simulator as a test device.